# PHP issue with displaying a mySQLi result

Tags: php, email, mysqli

I'm having a rather confusing issue with a result that will not display. I'm creating a mailshot application and I'm trying to populate the email with the recipients name as well as an advert. The result works fine when I store it for use with the email that it sends to but it wont display inside the email body. Its a little hard to explain but here is the code that I am using. I have removed a lot of the email body as it was pretty large, where the ... are that is where I've take a load out.

```html
<?php require (__DIR__.'/connections/connections.php');
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){
 }else{ 
  header('Location: login.php');
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>AzTecks Staff | Search Results</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coin-slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_resize">
      <div class="menu_nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php"><span>Staff Home</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Register_Client.php"><span>Register Client</span></a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="Register_Applicant.php"><span>Register Applicant</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="Add_vacancy.php"><span>Add Vacancy</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="logout.php"><span>Logout</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="index.php"><span>AzTecks</span> <small style=" height: 12px; font-size: 11px;"> We Advise, We Avertise,</small><small style=" height: 12px; font-size: 11px;"> We Guarantee Not To Compromise</small></a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content_resize">
      <div class="mainbar" style="margin-top:0px;">
   <?php
    echo "<div class=\"article\"><h2>Sending emails, please wait...</h2></div><br />";
    
    /*Variables for mail shot query*/
    $Keywords = $_SESSION['aKeywords'];
    $Lname = $_SESSION['aLname'];
    $Fname = $_SESSION['aFname']; 
    $CurrentJob = $_SESSION['aCurrentJob'];
    $DesiredJob = $_SESSION['aDesiredJob'];
    $CurrentSalary = $_SESSION['aCurrentSalary'];
    $DesiredSalary = $_SESSION['aDesiredSalary'];
    $Town = $_SESSION['aTown'];
    $Country = $_SESSION['aCountry'];
    $QualLevel = $_SESSION['aQualLevel'];
    $Languages = $_SESSION['aLanguages'];
    $TPC = $_SESSION['aTPC'];
    $TechnicalTerms = $_SESSION['aTechnicalTerms'];
    $ApplicantDivision = $_SESSION['aApplicantDivision'];
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Applicants WHERE (? IS NULL OR CV_Text LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Last_Name LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_First_Name LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Current_Job_Title LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Desired_Job_Title LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Current_Salary >= ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Desired_Salary >= ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Town LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Country LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Qualification_Level LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Languages LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR T_P_C LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Applicant_Division LIKE ?) AND (? IS NULL OR Technical_Terms LIKE ?)";
   
    $KeywordsW = '%'.$Keywords.'%';
    $LnameW = '%'.$Lname.'%';
    $FnameW = '%'.$Fname.'%';
    $CurrentJobW = '%'.$CurrentJob.'%';
    $DesiredJobW = '%'.$DesiredJob.'%';
    $TownW = '%'.$Town.'%';
    $CountryW = '%'.$Country.'%';
    $QualLevelW = '%'.$QualLevel.'%';
    $LanguagesW = '%'.$Languages.'%';
    $TPCW = '%'.$TPC.'%';
    $TechnicalTermsW = '%'.$TechnicalTerms.'%';
    $ApplicantDivisionW = '%'.$ApplicantDivision.'%';
    
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssiiiissssssssssssss", $Keywords, $KeywordsW, $Lname, $LnameW, $Fname, $FnameW, $CurrentJob, $CurrentJobW, $DesiredJob, $DesiredJobW, $CurrentSalary, $CurrentSalary, $DesiredSalary, $DesiredSalary, $Town, $TownW, $Country, $CountryW, $QualLevel, $QualLevelW, $Languages, $LanguagesW, $TPC, $TPCW, $ApplicantDivision, $ApplicantDivisionW, $TechnicalTerms, $TechnicalTermsW);
 
    $stmt->execute() or die("Something went wrong, could not search :-(");
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if ($count == 0) {
     $output = 'Sorry, no results found!';
     echo $output; 
    } 
    
    else {
     while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
     $id = $row->Applicant_ID;
     $queryResult = $con->query("SELECT Contact_Email FROM Client_Contacts WHERE Contact_ID = {$_SESSION['coID']}");
     $ContactDetails = $queryResult->fetch_object();
     $email = $ContactDetails->Contact_Email;
     $firstname = $row->Applicant_First_Name;
     $lastname = $row->Applicant_Last_Name;
     
     $mail_body = "<!doctype html>
<html>

...                           
                            Hello ".$ContactDetails->Contact_First_Name." ".$ContactDetails->Contact_Last_Name."<br /><br /><br />
                            
                            Below is a potential applicant for your consideration.<br /><br />".$row->Applicant_Advert."<br /><br />
                            
                           
...</html>";
     $subject = $_SESSION['eSubject'];
     $headers = "From:natalie@aztecksonline.net\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n";
     $to = $email;
     
     $mail_result = mail($to,$subject,$mail_body,$headers);
     
    }
    }
    
    if($mail_result) {
     echo "<script>window.alert(\"Mail Shot Sent!\");</script>";
     
     header('location: index.php'); 
    } else {
     echo "Something went wrong :-("; 
    }
   ?>
   
      </div>
      
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="searchform">
          <form id="formsearch" name="formsearch" method="post" action="#">
            <span>
            <input name="editbox_search" class="editbox_search" id="editbox_search" maxlength="80" value="Search Applicants" type="text" />
            </span>
            <input name="button_search" src="images/search.gif" class="button_search" type="image" />
          </form>
          <br />
          <div class="clr"><div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
     new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
   }
    </script>
   </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="gadget">
          <h2 class="star"><span>Sidebar</span> Menu</h2>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <ul class="sb_menu">
            <li><a href="index.php">Staff Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register_Client.php">Register Client</a><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="Register_Applicant.php">Register Applicant</a></li>
            <li><a href="Add_Vacancy.php">Add Vacancy</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="gadget">
          <h2 class="star"><span>Recent Vacancies</span></h2>
          <div class="clr"></div>
          <ul class="ex_menu">
          
          <?php
    
    if($cat_side_result = $con->query("SELECT Vacancy_ID, Vacancy_Job_Title, Vacancy_Location FROM Vacancies LIMIT 6")) {
    if($cat_side_result->num_rows) {
     while($cat_side_row = $cat_side_result->fetch_object()) {
      echo '<li><a href="View_Vacancy_Category.php?id='.$cat_side_row->Vacancy_ID.'">'.$cat_side_row->Vacancy_Job_Title.'</a><br /> In '.$cat_side_row->Vacancy_Location.'</li>';
      
      mysqli_close($con);
      }
    }
    }
        ?>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fbg">
    <div class="fbg_resize">
      <div class="col c1">
        <h2>Clients Recently Joined</h2>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/Small_Company_logo_ABP.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="gal" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/Jumpahead1.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="gal" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/Keopple_logo_small.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="gal" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/Phantom_small.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="gal" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/graves-capital_small.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="gal" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="images/global-financial-logo_small.gif" width="75" height="75" alt="" class="gal" /></a> </div>
      <div class="col c2">
        <h2><span>Services</span> Overview</h2>
        <p>At AzTecks we are committed to insuring you have total confidentiality, and do not share any data or information without your say so, please read our privacy agreement for more information.</p>
        <ul class="fbg_ul">
          <li><a href="about.php">More about us</a></li>
          <li><a href="Register-Coming_Soon.php">Privacy agreement</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col c3">
        <h2><span>Contact</span> Us</h2>
        <p>If you have any querys about us or have any questions please feel free to contact us.</p>
        <p class="contact_info"> <span>Address:</span>1 Shaw Street<br />
          Worcester , Worcestershire , UK<br />
           <span>Postcode:</span> WR1 3QQ<br />
         <span>Telephone:</span> 01905 700158<br />
          <span>E-mail:</span><a href="#">info@aztecksonline.net</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_resize">
      <p class="lf">&copy; Copyright <a href="index.php">AzTecks</a>.</p>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the $email populates fine as it sends the email with no issue but where it says in the email body `$ContactDetails->Contact_First_Name`, it does not display at all.

Have I done something rather dumb or is there something else wrong?

Comment: So do we really need to read all these codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT Contact_Email, Contact_First_Name, Contact_Last_Name FROM Client_Contacts WHERE Contact_ID = {$_SESSION['coID']}
```

You forgot to add `Contact_First_Name` and `Contact_Last_Name` into it so it wasn't even fetching them.

Comment: oh my giddy aunt! This is a prime example of staring at the code to long! You are bang on the money! Feel really dumb now ha ha. Thanks a lot for your help! I would up vote you but I'm afraid I haven't got enough rep :-(

Comment: glad I could help a fellow coder.

Answer (score -1):

Start by adding at the top.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

And then add a die(); or exit(); before you actually execute any database updates and then check what is the error in the errors shown by php.

Normally this is because of an illegal way of executing the SQL in question. Try it out.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: Appreciate the reply but user5200287 is right on this. Was a daft mistake on my part ¬_¬ Thanks though!

Answer (score -2):

At first, you should write a readable code.

Now it's a really bad spaghetti code with crazy indentation (read about PSRs).

After that, separate your PHP from HTML, and move interaction with database to a different layer.

Comment: this isn't code review, but you are right

Comment: I know, but if someone's an error in a code like OPs, refactoring is the only proper way to go.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It should be a comment.

Comment: Completely agree with you on that tbh, very good shout. I have gotten a bit lazy with this page as its taken ages for me to write. Still quite new to PHP! Will clean this up before the release :-)